# How to stop a tokenizer not split words further?

Tags: python, nlp, huggingface-tokenizers, huggingface

In the following code below, the tokenizer is splitting some of the words. Is it the property of the model or can I somehow force it not to split the words? I am using these tokens for inference to model.  Even after passing
`do_basic_tokenize: False`, it is still splitting the words.

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer
text = "Patient John Doe visited the hospital on 01/05/2023 with complaints of chest pain."
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("obi/deid_bert_i2b2", tokenizer_args={"do_basic_tokenize": False})
tokens = tokenizer.tokenize(text, truncation=True, padding=True, return_tensors="pt")
model = AutoModelForTokenClassification.from_pretrained("obi/deid_bert_i2b2")
tokens
```

Output:

```
['Pat',
 '##ient',
 'John',
 'Do',
 '##e',
 'visited',
 'the',
 'hospital',
 'on',
 '01',
 '/',
 '05',
 '/',
 '202',
 '##3',
 'with',
 'complaints',
 'of',
 'chest',
 'pain',
 '.']
```

Is there any efficient way/package to combine the  tokens with hashes with its predecessor or successor in the text?

Comment: Why don't you use NLTK. I say so because, it would make the task presented trivial.

Comment: @Quant1892387 I am using same model for inference later

Comment: I see. Ok. Do you want to manipulate the output list? Or do you want to avoid the behavior? If you want to manipulate the list, I still don't understand why not use NLTK and feed that into the model. Why are you using BERT? Anyways, Pseudo code: if token starts with # then chomp '#' and join with token[-1]

Answer (score 0):

When using the `AutoTokenizer` from `transformers`, the pre-trained tokenizers usually split the inputs into sentence/wordpieces, see https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/tokenizer_summary

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForTokenClassification

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("obi/deid_bert_i2b2", tokenizer_args={"do_basic_tokenize": False})

text = "Patient John Doe visited the hospital on 01/05/2023 with complaints of chest pain."
tokens = tokenizer.tokenize(text, truncation=True, padding=True, return_tensors="pt")

print(tokens)
```

[out]:

> ['Pat', '##ient', 'John', 'Do', '##e', 'visited', 'the', 'hospital', 'on', '01', '/', '05', '/', '202', '##3', 'with', 'complaints', 'of', 'chest', 'pain', '.']

And to map these "sentencepiece" tokens to their vocabulary IDs in the tokenizer, you can do this:

```
tokenizer.convert_tokens_to_ids(tokens)
```

[out]:

> [7195, 9080, 1287, 2091, 1162, 3891, 1103, 2704, 1113, 5187, 120, 4991, 120, 17881, 1495, 1114, 11344, 1104, 2229, 2489, 119]

And to "stitch" the text back, you can use the `.decode` function:

```
tokenizer.decode(tokenizer.convert_tokens_to_ids(tokens))
```

[out]:

```
Patient John Doe visited the hospital on 01 / 05 / 2023 with complaints of chest pain.
```

---

**Note:** the `do_basic_tokenize` option is not to avoid the sentencepiece / wordpiece breaking but to tell the function whether to do pre-tokenization before call the sentencepiece tokenizer https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/main/src/transformers/models/bert/tokenization_bert.py#L149

> do_basic_tokenize (`bool`, *optional*, defaults to `True`):
> Whether or not to do basic tokenization before WordPiece.